# How to place single image on multiple pages by jspdf?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, jspdf

I am having html page which contain very lengthy data.

Here, I have to convert html to pdf. I cant able to convert pdf with css by using jspdf

So i have planned. First convert html to png by canvas and then convert png to pdf. I got correct method to do this. I got solution also.

But Problem is After converting png, im not able to place in pdf, Image will be cropped.

This is my code

```
window.onload = function() {
                html2canvas(document.body).then(function(canvas) {
        document.getElementById("page1").appendChild(canvas);
                    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
                    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
                     l = {
                         orientation: 'p',
                         unit: 'pt',
                         format: 'a3',
                         compress: true,
                         fontSize: 8,
                         lineHeight: 1,
                         autoSize: false,
                         printHeaders: true
                     };

                    var doc = new jsPDF(l, "", "", "");



                    doc.addImage(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"), 'jpeg',0,0)
                    doc.addPage();
            doc.addImage(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"), 'jpeg',0,500, 1000, 1000)
                    window.location=doc.output("datauristring")
                });
            }
```

After converting pdf, I am showing in same tab.

I have tried another method.

Divide html page into two section. First section will be in first page in pdf and remaining will be in second page in pdf. After that, I have to shown in browser.

I am not able to do this.

Anyone Can give solution for this one?

Answer (score 0):

l = {
                         orientation: 'p',
                         unit: 'pt',
                         format: 'a3',
                         compress: true,
                         fontSize: 8,
                         lineHeight: 1,
                         autoSize: false,
                         printHeaders: true
                     };

var doc = new jsPDF(l);

doc.addHTML($('elementHTML'),{format:'png',pagesplit: true}});